# Laravel 5.4 Update - SHA Hasher Illegal offset type in unset in Singleton

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm migrating from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.4. We have a custom SHA hasher from a previous application.

In the Laravel 5.4 patch notes, it is shown that `share()` has been removed and `singleton()` is to replace it.

I've got the application up and running except for the newly updated hasher. When I change my share function to singleton I get the following error:

```
ErrorException: Illegal offset type in unset in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:1090
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/App/app/Libraries/SHAHashServiceProvider.php(13): Illuminate\Container\Container->singleton(Object(Closure))
```

I have the newly updated hasher is as following:

```
public function register() {
    $this->app['hash'] = $this->app->singleton(function () {
        return new SHAHasher();
    });

}
```

What am I doing wrong here with the singleton function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the docs have for creating a singleton:

```
$this->app->singleton('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
});
```

Doesn't match what you have.

[Laravel Docs - 5.4 - Service Container - Bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#binding)